# Updating Model and adding a new object to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an entity as follows:

```
class Project{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   ... some other props
   public virtual Image Image {set;get;}
}
```

on controller I have the following:

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Project project, HttpPostedFileBase file1)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file1 != null)
                {
                    var path = FileUploadHelper.UploadFile(file1, Server.MapPath(ProjectImages));

                    var image = new Image { ImageName = file1.FileName, Path = path, ContentType = file1.ContentType };

                    var imageEntity = db.Images.Add(image);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    project.MainImage = imageEntity;
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("FileEmpty", "You need to upload a file.");
                    return View(project);
                }

                db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(project);
        }
```

Problem here is when I read the Project for this record, i still see the old image. ie: it is not updating the image for a given project entity.

Why is this happening?

I can load the project from DB and assign the value to it. but why this is not working? can i get it working without loading the object from db?

Comment: Does the images gets added to the database? And do the other properties of the `Project` gets updated? How about assigning the `image` (not `imageEntity`) variable to the `MainImage` property and call `db.SaveChanges()` just once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your project object is not attached to the context
Try this

```
            if (file1 != null)
            {
                var path = FileUploadHelper.UploadFile(file1, Server.MapPath(ProjectImages));

                var image = new Image { ImageName = file1.FileName, Path = path, ContentType = file1.ContentType };
                db.Project.Attach(project);
                db.Images.Add(image);                    
                project.MainImage = image;
                context.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

And remove this at the end of your POST method:

```
            db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries. this is what i m getting after what you suggested.

Comment: and that s because the new image i uploaded has no `Id`. I guess

Comment: EF knows the order to do Insert and Update, the problem does not come from here. Do you have any concurrency checking?

Comment: How do you use EF? Code First? Database First? Model First?

Comment: Try this for testing, instead of attaching the project to the context, Fetch the project from the database and update the fetched project.

Comment: well that works as i mentioned in the question. I can fetch it assign the values etc and save it. that s fine. but what s wrong with this? the other way is too long and boring.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33302/discussion-between-swell-and-darthvader)

Answer (score -2):

Darth, I have dealt with this before and it is an insane quirk with MVC.  You are changing your model in a post method and returning it to the same view. It will not pass the new value back to the view without clearing the value first.

```
ModelState.Remove("MainImage");
ModelState.SetValue("MainImage", imageEntity);
```

Or

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

and then rebuild the model completely.  I know it sounds crazy, but, been there, done that, and nothing else will work in this scenario.

Comment: I'm surprised this got down voted.  The reason the image is not going back in the model is that on a post method you must either clear the model and reconstruct it, or clear the individual field in the model and assign it a new value.  It is a quirk in MVC that if you don't do this it will keep its value from before the post.

Answer (score -2):

Disable the automatic cache in MVC and in your browser so it can update to the newest version every time.

You can use the OutputCacheAttribute to control server and/or browser caching for specific actions or all actions in a controller.

**Disable for all actions in a controller:**

```
[OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)] // will be applied to all actions in MyController, unless those actions override with their own decoration
public class MyController : Controller
{
  // ... 
}
```

**Disable for a specific action:**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam = "*", Duration = 0, NoStore = true)] // will disable caching for Index only
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you talking about